# How to use a column of index values to create a new column in a separate dataset

Tags: perl, indexing, hash, hashset

I have been having trouble with coupling values together between two datasets and I was wondering if someone could help me. I think I am close to a solution so hopefully someone can point out what might be wrong.

So I have two types of datasets. One looks like this, let's call it dataset1:

```css
1 Asia 
2 Australia
3 Europe
```

dataset1 contains my reference set where every number is linked to a value.
The other dataset, dataset2, looks something like this:

```css
4638  3
14372 3
4464  1
3498  2
```

What I want to do is use the values of the second column from dataset2 and find the associated index value on the dataset1 so that I add a new column like this:

```html
4638  3 Europe  
14372 3 Europe  
4464  1 Asia
3498  2 Australia
```

What I tried to do is create a hash of the values in the first dataset and use them as reference for the second database like this:

```html
open($fh, "<", $dataset1) || die "Could not open file $dataset $!/n"; 

while (<$fh>) {
    @tmp = split /\t/, $_;
    $area{$tmp[0]} = $tmp[1];
}

open($fh2, "<", $dataset2) || die "Could not open file $dataset $!/n;

while (<$fh2>) {
   @tmp2 = split /\t/, $_;
    $code = $tmp2[0];
    $index= $tmp2[1];
    if(defined($area{$index})){
        print "$code\t$index\t$area{$index}\n";
    }
}
```

When I execute the above command, I get no warnings but nothing is printed out. I assume there is an issue with the "defined" section but I am not sure how to resolve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Best,
A.

Comment: `chomp`, `chomp`, `chomp`

Comment: Yes it works!!! I was sure it was something small and silly like this, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go. I used a hash ref, because I like them I think your split on \t was causing the main issue of not being able to map correctly.

`EDIT: added chomp and ability to deal with space separated language names`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ds1_map;

open(my $fh1, "<", 'dataset1') || die "Could not open file dataset1 $!/n"; 
while (my $line = <$fh1> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my @tmp = split(/\s+/, $line);
    my $i = shift @tmp;
    my $str = join(' ', @tmp);
    $ds1_map->{$i} = $str;
}
close $fh1;

open(my $fh2, "<", 'dataset2') || die "Could not open file dataset2 $!/n";
while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($code, $index) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    if(defined($ds1_map->{$index})){
        print "$code\t$index\t$ds1_map->{$index}\n";
    }
}
close $fh2;
```

Comment: Just use `chomp` already, or you will be sad the first time you encounter something like `North America` in the first dataset.

Comment: Don't use `@tmp` when you could write `my ($code, $index) = split ...`.

Comment: @Dada ... or go crazy with anonymous arrays **;-)** ... `[split]->[1]`. See my response for an example of this kind of abuse with bonus `IO::All` madness. Seriously though `split` and autosplit (`-a` & `@F` on the command line) are simple but powerful - like perl.  +1 for the LHS use of `()` for list context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it that takes anonymous arrays created by `split`-ing each line in the reference data file and `map`-ing their elements into a set of hash keys/values.

NB: I have used [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) to shorten the script, it may not be efficient to slurp very large files in this way.

```
use IO::All ;                       
my @idx = io->file("dataset1.txt")->chomp->slurp  ;               
my @data = io->file("dataset2.txt")->chomp->slurp  ;

# make an index hash_ref with successive elements of split lines           
my $index_hr = { map { [split]->[0] => [split]->[1] } @idx };

# print lines where the second element matches index hashref key
foreach my $line (@data) {                                
  my $key = (split /\s+/, $line)[1] ;                              
  print join " ", $line, $index_hr->{$key}, "\n" ;    
}
```

**Output**

```
4638  3 Europe 
14372 3 Europe 
4464  1 Asia 
3498  2 Australia
```